# Knockout condition bind click: binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, conditional-statements

Hi guys I have a very simple example for you:

```
<h4 data-bind="text: title, click: editTitle, visible: view() == 'read' || view() == 'description' || view() == 'dueDate' || view() == 'members'" id="headTitle"></h4>
```

As you can see I already have `click` and `visibility` binding on this heading.

Is there anyway to also include `if: isOwner(id)` binding on this?

I want to allow users to envoke `click` only if `isOwner(id)` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add it inside the click event handler?

```
self.editTitle= function(){
    if(self.isOwner(self.id())){
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: Beats me why I didn't think of that !? Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Actually I run into a problem with this approach. Every time I open parent containing title tag it always triggers ``self.editTitle``. It seem to be related to the way I passed id parameter into it from the view i.e. ``<h4...data-bind"...click: editTitle(id),..``. But it definitely does the trick.

Comment: Hehe, silly me. Totally forgot that I passed id reference into knockout model just for occasions like this. Now time to make use of it.